# Search thru arrayList using .contains()

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

Im trying to search thru my arrylist using .contains().

This is the method I have in my window class:

```
    public void findByID() {
    int customer = Integer.parseInt(findCustomerField.getText());

    if (userA.list.contains(customer)) {
        User user = userA.findById(customer);
        output.setText(user.toString());
    }
}
```

In my previous version I used the customerID to find the customer, my findByID method in my UserArchive class looked like this:

```
    public User findById(int id) {
    for (User u : list) {
        if (u.getCustomerID() == id) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null; // or empty User
}
```

How should the last method look if I want to use .contains()? I think the window class method is alright, not sure tho. Im feel clueless using contains (just heard of it yesterday).

Edit: I dont want to user the customerID to find a object anymore(thats what the previous version did) My goal is to be able to type for example "Peter" and then find all objects containing "Peter". After what I understand this is possible by using the .contains() in some way.

Edit 2: I got it to work. Now I can search for a specific firstName and print it out. Edit goal: what I really wanted is to search for for example "Pe" and then get every object in the list that contains "Pe" not only first names. Will look into what Akshay Singhal posted. Heres the methods that worked for the firstName:

Window class:

```
    public void findByID() {
    String customer = findCustomerField.getText();

    if (!customer.equals("")) {
        User user = userA.findByName(customer);
        output.setText(user.toString());
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Does not exist");
}
```

UserArchive class:

```
    public User findByName(String name) {
    for (User u : list) {
        if (u.getFirstName().equals(name)) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is your list a list of Integers (customer ids) or a list of User Objects (customers)?

Comment: Its a list of User Objects. the last method is the one i used in my previous version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve your problem using `contains()`. That method searches for an object in your list, whereas you need to search based on an *attribute* of an object in your list.

Your current code looks correct.

---

Regarding your recent edit:

> My goal is to be able to type for example "Peter" and then find all objects containing "Peter".

In that case, you need very similar code. Just loop around until you find an object that has that property:

```
public User findByName(String name) {
    for (User u : list) {
        if (u.getName().equals(name)) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: technically it's possible (new user with given id, and an equals in terms of id equality), but I agree with your answer

Comment: @szegedi Yes, I guess that might work. But I would consider that abuse of the purpose of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

contains method checks whether an object is present in the collection. That basically means determining whether the object being checked is **equal** to any object in the collection.

For establishing this equality the equals method of the object is used.

In this case you need to override equals method in your user object to say that 2 user objects are equal when their ID's are same.

After that you can check directly using contains.

Note: Don't forget to override the hash code method as well.

Comment: The current code has no access to a `User` object. The problem the OP is trying to solve *is* resolving a `User` object from an ID. This solution doesn't help.

Comment: OP has already resolved the problem. I think the question, at least to me, seems more about how to apply contains in this case. This answer clearly tells what needs to be done to apply contains. It is upto OP whether this is feasible in his/her context.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your list, and the frequency with which this code is executed, the custom-iterate-till-you-find-a-match method you are trying might be ok, but if frequent lookups are expected, you may want to try one if these approaches:

1. Instead of a list, create a HashMap of customer Id as Key and the corresponding User object as the value. This method should provide you near response time regardless of the fact that the user id provided was at the top of the list or bottom.
2. You could also use Collections.sort with a custom comparator that compares the ids of User objects to sort the list, and then Collections.binarySearch to search, again with a comparator that looks only at the User's id. As an input you could just create a new User object and set it's Id to the one you are searching for.

Answer (score -1):

Think about overriding hashcode and equals of your Person-class to identify your objects.

Also look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

To use it, you should override the equals() and hashCode() method of User in a way like this:

public boolean equals(Object o){

.... some standard stuff like is Null and instanceof

return this.getCustomerID() == ((User) o).getCustomerID();

}

if you use eclipse you can generate it.

Comment: The current code has no access to a `User` object. The problem the OP is trying to solve *is* resolving a `User` object from an ID. This solution doesn't help.